# What happens, and why, when an update cursor is run a second time?

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I want to know what happens when I run my update cursor twice in SQL Server.

I have already run my update cursor twice. The first time I ran the cursor, it gave me 19370 rows that needed to be updated. When I ran the same cursor a second time, it gave me just one row that needs to be update.

```
set nocount on;

declare @playerID varchar(255)
declare @total_g_all int

declare @today date
set @today = (CONVERT(date, getdate()))

declare @updateCount bigint
set @updateCount = 0

declare @stop int
set @stop = 0

print @today
Print 'Transaction Update Command Start Time - ' + (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))
--Declare Cursor
declare update_cursor cursor static for 
    select app.playerID, sum(G_all) as total_g_all
    from Appearances app right outer join People ppl
    on app.playerID = ppl.playerID
    where (jnk22_Date_Last_Update != @today or jnk22_Date_Last_Update is null)
    group by app.playerID
Select @@CURSOR_ROWS as 'Number of Cursor Rows After Declare'
Print 'Declare Cursor Complete Time - ' + (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))

--Open Cursor
open update_cursor

--c. Selects the system variable @@Cursor_Rows after you open the CURSOR so you can see how many rows are in the cursor. 
Select @@CURSOR_ROWS as 'Number of Cursor Rows'  
--19183 rows

--b. updates the NJIT_Total_Games_Played with the sum of G_ALL column from the cursor and sets NJIT_Date_Last_Update to the 
--   current date.
fetch next from update_cursor into @playerID, @total_g_all
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 and @stop = 0
begin
    if @updateCount = 0
        BEGIN 
            PRINT 'Begin Transaction At Record - ' + RTRIM(CAST(@updateCount AS nvarchar(30))) + ' At - ' + 
                (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
    END
    update People
    set jnk22_Total_Games_Played = @total_g_all where @playerID = playerID

    update People
    set jnk22_Date_Last_Update = @today where @playerID = playerID

    set @updateCount = @updateCount + 1

--d. Prints the start and stop date and time as well as the  # of records updated with the date and time for every 1,000 
--   records updated
    IF @updateCount % 1000 = 0 
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'START TRANSACTION - ' + RTRIM(CAST(@updateCount AS nvarchar(30))) + ' At - ' + 
                            (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))
            PRINT 'COMMIT TRANSACTION - ' + RTRIM(CAST(@updateCount AS nvarchar(30))) + ' At - ' + 
                            (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            PRINT 'STOP TRANSACTION - ' + RTRIM(CAST(@updateCount AS nvarchar(30))) + ' At - ' + 
                            (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))
        END
    FETCH NEXT FROM update_cursor INTO @playerID, @total_g_all
    END

    IF @stop <> 1
    BEGIN
            PRINT 'Final Commit Transaction For Record - ' + RTRIM(CAST(@updateCount AS nvarchar(30))) + ' At - ' + 
                        (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
    END

    IF @stop = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Rollback started For Transaction at Record - ' + RTRIM(CAST(@updateCount AS nvarchar(30))) + ' At - ' +
                                    (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))
        Rollback TRANSACTION
    END

--e. Closes and deallocates the cursor as the last step in the script.
CLOSE update_cursor
DEALLOCATE update_cursor
print 'Transaction Update Command End Date - ' + (CAST(convert(date, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))
Print 'Transaction Update Command End Time - ' + (CAST(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) AS nvarchar(30)))

set nocount off;
```

Actual result is "1" => number of rows being updated when cursor is run twice.
I want to know why.

Comment: What do you mean by 'when cursor is run twice' = are you running this entire code block twice or just the bits from open update_cursor?

Comment: Entire code I ran it twice. That’s when the @@cursor_rows value was displayed as 1. I want to know why that happens

Comment: you have to answer that yourself. Check which row is being updated on 2nd run. And is that row included in the 1st run, if it does, what value is it updated to